# Securely Allow PHP Read & Write Access to System Files

Tags: php, linux, security

I have not been able to find solid information on preferred (best practices) and/or secure methods to allow php to access config or other types of files on a linux server not contained in the public web directory or owned by the apache user so I'm hoping to find some answers here.

I am a fairly competent PHP programmer but am increasingly tasked with writing web applications (most of which are not publicly accessible via the web however) that require updating, changing or adding to config files or files generated by some service or application on the server.

For instance, I need to create a web interface that will view, add or remove entries from a /etc/mail/spamassassin/white-list.cf file owned by root.

Another scenario is that I need php to parse mime messages in /var/vmail that are owned by user vmail.

These are just a couple examples, there will be other files in locations owned by other processes/users. How can I write PHP applications that securely access and manipulate these files without opening security risks?

Comment: I would not recommend any unauthenticated write access to files owned by root.  Having said that, if you are very strict with validating user input and very careful with how you share ownership of the individual file........I still wouldn't do this.  Use `cpanel`, `webmin` or some other web based administration tool that already has these functions and security built in.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the input. However I'm not asking for a utility or application to manage a server via the web. I'm looking for best practices for PHP code to access files outside the web directory and owned by other users. In other words i would like to take the same approach as cpanel, webmin etc.

Comment: My general strategy is to offload the stuff changed by www-data into a temporary file or DB, then having a separate PHP script that's owned and executed by root (as a cronjob) that parses said input actually performs the config overwrite.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If I were needing to implement something like this, I would probably look at using something like `sudo` to fine-tune permissions. I'm not a Linux CLI expert, so I'm sure there are issues that I haven't taken into account when typing this out.

I would probably determine what tasks need to be done, and would write a separate script for each task that needs to be completed. Using `sudo`, I'd assign the necessary level of permissions for that script only.

Obviously, as the number of tasks increase, so would the complexity and the amount of work involved. I'm not sure how this would affect you at the moment.

Comment: Thank you, I believe this is heading in the right direction. Currently I tackle these problems by populating information in a database via a php web interface and then have a cronjob that checks for new database entries and updates the needed files accordingly, acting as a "middle man". Although I believe this is a secure way to accomplish these tasks I feel it may be a little overly complicated.

Comment: To clarify, you are suggesting permanently assigning permissions to relevant scripts & files or using shell_exec() to temporarily assign the necessary permissions and revert back at end of script?

Comment: I would use the `sudo` configuration file to permanently assign the permissions. So, given a script `/usr/bin/updatesomefile`, use `sudo` to allow the PHP user to execute `sudo /usr/bin/updatesomefile` using `shell_exec` (or similar). Within `/usr/bin/updatesomefile` you have all your updating logic.